# Polyurethane coating on fabric

Tags: materials, chemical-engineering

I want to use a mix of polyurethane and acetone to coat some polyester fabric. I have the choice between using a PU glue or a PU foam but because polyurethane isn't [a single material](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_polyurethane_applications#/media/File:Purgrid.png) with a fixed composition but rather a range of chemicals sharing similar chemistry, I wonder which one would be better.

I want the lightest coating possible it should be water proof as well as UV resistant one.

So here are my questions:

● Should I go with a PU glue or a foam?

● Will the UV resistant property of the foam would still work once it is dissolved in acetone?

Comment: What about a PU designed to be a coating?

Answer (score 2):

There are two main types of polyurethane : Aliphatic and Aromatic.

Aliphatic offer better UV resistance (so it can retain its gloss and color really well). They're common for exterior coating formulations.

Aromatic have better chemical resistance but are not as resistant to UV. But they are usually applied in a fairly thin film (Commonly used in marine and industrial applications)

In terms of chemical resistance, that depends on the specific coating system but here's a rough list : http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/polyurethane-chemical-resistance-d_1878.html

As for glue or foam I'm not too sure.